# In C#, when testing several UDP sockets running on Timers, what resource limitations will be reached first?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, udp, udpclient

Ok this might be a vague question, but I'll try to keep it specific!

In C#, I'm running 1 server that listens for UDP sockets. The server runs a `Timer` object to monitor the client's `last packet sent "time"` to decide whether to forget it after 15 seconds.

For each of the UDP clients launched (in their own process / terminal), they ALSO run their own `Timer` object to send a packet every now and then (more or less to keep it alive).

Now, I ran a stress test and could "only" reach about 104 simultaneous UDP clients connections in their own terminals / command-line windows. After that, it just gives up and shows me this:

[image]

So, being new to network programming and all, I don't have a sweet clue which specific resource it ran-out off or what limit it reached to cause it to hang at that specific *nth* process. Makes it difficult to understand how some frameworks claim to reach >100,000 concurrent connections!

Now, if I was to take a few guesses, I'm thinking I've ran into a limit of:

- UDP sockets?
- Used up as much concurrent ports the OS allows?
- Timers the OS can process? (I sure hope not!)
- Too many terminal windows open, especially from the same process *.exe?
- Thread-Locking the wrong parts / at the wrong time?
- Maybe my tests are just wrong / poorly conducted? (Maybe instead of testing individual UDP clients in their own process, I should batch a few in the same terminal?)

For the more visual, here's basically what's happening:
[image: myudp-test-connection crashes on 104th connection]

Comment: Impossible to say with any certainty. Although I'd be really surprised if it was timers. I've had thousands of concurrent timers in a single application before. My best advice would be to add an exception handler in your `Main`, to see if you can catch and display an exception that's being thrown. And if that doesn't work, add a lot of logging and exception handling in your code so that you can see what's happening.

Comment: It's definitely *not* connections, because UDP is by definition a connectionless protocol.

Comment: UDP is a connectionless protocol, and when you write code that listens for messages it is listening on just one socket (probably), so what may be happening is that you're not processing the incoming messages fast enough and the network code is getting backed up.  A standard approach for this kind of code is to receive the message, put it into a queue for another thread to process, and then immediately wait for another incoming message.

Comment: Definitely sounds like good advice @RayFischer, will give that a shot.

Comment: @JimMischel True, can't hurt to place a few extra try-catch blocks in the right places, will try that!